# How to add default constraint with condition in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, constraints, sql-server-2014

I am using Sql Server 2014

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Record](
    [RecordId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BookId] [int] NULL,
    [TopicId] [int] NULL,
    [BookName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [TopicName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [RecordPath] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [RecordName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [DurationInSec] [float] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Record] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RecordId] ASC
)


ALTER TABLE dbo.Record ADD CONSTRAINT DC_RecordPath DEFAULT
             (CASE WHEN BookId = 1 THEN 'path/to/1' ELSE RecordPath END)
```

I want a default constraint with condition as above, but this is not permitted.
Is there any workaround without using triggers?

**Edit:** Computed column is not working, because the column is filled by a few stored procedures.
I have two conditions;

1. If `BookId` is 1 then `RecordPath` is path 1
2. Else for any `BookId`, `RecordPath` is `RecordPath` comes from stored procedure

Comment: It sounds like you really need a computed column

Comment: @Lamak I added to question why computed column does not fit.

Comment: @Lamak actually doesn't work because computed columns doesn't create a constraint.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I know. I meant that this didn't sound like the constraint is needed at all, just a computed column

Comment: Do you want a `DEFAULT` value or a `CONSTRAINT` to make sure the value is always correct. If compute column doesnt work. You can use a `TRIGGER`

Comment: What about book 10 or 100 or 10001? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the question and code to clarify..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need if you need that to check only the record with `BookId = 1`

```
CHECK (BookId = 1 AND RecordPath = 'path/to/1') OR (BookId != 1)
```

Esentialy this says: If BookId equals to 1, then the path has to be the one specified, or the BookId can be anything else and for those records the record path can be anything.

`RecordPath = RecordPath` is not necessary for the second part, since it is always `TRUE`

**Or do you want a computed default?**

That is not possible, DEFAULT constraint cannot depend on other columns. To achieve something similar, you'll need a TRIGGER or you can use a computed column or a view instead and use that column/view in your application when reading data.

Comment: Since check constraint can not assign value to the column which I need, I can not make use of that. What I'm looking was a computed & assignable/updatable column (can we say hybrid?) I guess I am going to use triggers.

Comment: If you have to solve it in one column, you'll have to use triggers. However if you just want a computed default value, a computed column can help if you write only the original column and read the computed one. Essentially the computed column is a simple `COALESCE(RecordPath, CONCAT('path/to/', BookId))` or a view with an `INSTEAD INSERT` trigger on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Record ADD CONSTRAINT DC_RecordPath 
      CHECK ((CASE WHEN BookId = 1 THEN 'path/to/1' ELSE 'path/to/2' END)=RecordPath)
```

Comment: I have just tried, this doesn't fill the column `RecordPath`, it comes `null`